# Poppler Utils pdftohtml Turkish Character problem

Tags: linux, pdf, centos7, wkhtmltopdf, pdf-to-html

I am using pdftohtml package to convert PDF to HTML. However, some characters do not appear when I output HTML. I am giving the following parameters to the pdftohtml package. Normally, the font name in the PDF is Times New Roman. How can I solve this problem?

```
pdftohtml -s -enc UTF-8 -fontfullname -nomerge -noframes input.pdf output.html
```

[image: Problem]
[image: PDFTOHTML settings]

Comment: Would be helpful if you paste the images (screenshots?) into the question instead of hiding them behind some spurious links …

Comment: @tquadrat I don't have 10 reputation points.